Are the Tsinghua bamboo strips authentic?
I'm looking for a breakdown of the authenticity of the Tsinghua Bamboo Strips. I was reading some reviews of Yuri Pines' book Zhou History Unearthed (Columbia University Press, 2020), and I came across Hans van Ess' 2023 review, in which he casts doubt on the authenticity of the bamboo slips. In particular, the text on the strips seems anachronistic:

On the other hand, the reader is struck by the way how this text apparently complies with certain rules that scholars have agreed on in the twenty-first century: The Bamboo Annals as quoted in the "Suoyin" commentary are always right, while the information in Shi ji is always wrong; states are always called bang 邦, never as in Han times guo 國. The rulers of Chu are always Kings, not viscounts as in traditionally transmitted texts since newly available materials obviously were not exposed to the erroneous ideas by Han Confucians. Other rulers – with the exception of the "Marquis of Lu" – always have their correct titles, Marquis Wen of Jin obviously is a marquis, not a duke, other than it was the writing practice of traditionally transmitted texts where gong may just have been an honorary posthumous title given to him and to other rulers who were not dukes in the Zhou hierarchy. Xinian here seems to correct a mistake that has puzzled modern scholars although it may not have been a mistake. When rulers die this is never recorded with the word hong 薨 as reserved in the Liji and other texts for them but with the ordinary zu 卒 that, according to Liji, should be used for dignitaries.​

After going through some various problems with the strips, the conclusive evidence seemed particularly damning:

But it seems obvious that the person who wrote this text was not very well versed in non-historical sources from ancient Chinese philosophy and literature. Otherwise he would have known that the "One-Thousand-mu" plot and the "revenue field" had been combined only as late as by Zhang Heng in Latter Han times and that the phrase tianxia jiabing sounded familiar only to readers of the Ming novel Dong Zhou lieguo zhi, not to those of classical Chinese historical literature.​

I'm no specialist in ancient Chinese history, so how much of this makes sense? What other evidence has been marshaled in favor or against the slips' authenticity? Of course, the review is recent, but the slips have been out for a while now.

I had a very brief glance at the critique, but all I gathered from the "damning" evidence is something along the lines of these combination of phrases haven't been seen before in texts in the same era, and are only found much later. I find that a rather weak critique. To me, "damning" evidence looks like finding a character shape that definitely wasn't invented until much later, but used to represent an ancient word.

@dROOOze It would be if that phrase was coined much later. And that "much later" is one thousand years later, and it's used in the same context. But I'm no expert, that's why I asked.

I don't agree, because the individual vocabulary components of the phrases the critique is mentioning (天下、甲兵、千畝) already exists contemporary to the time the bamboo slips were purportedly authored, and already with the meaning as used in the phrases (天下之甲兵, etc.). If two authors living 1,000 years apart had the same vocabulary to work with, I don't think it's surprising if they combine vocabulary to come up with the same phrases.

@dROOOze I'm just thinking in the hypothetical. I have no idea.
